# How to open link in same tab from Power App / SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps, sharepoint-list

I have a Power App that is integrated with a SharePoint list and would like to have a link open in the same tab when a user saves their changes or cancels them. I also added a button in the app that goes to a link but it opens in a different tab.

Is there a way to get the link to open in the **same tab** when a user clicks the button and saves or cancels their edits?

Using **Launch(“URL”)** works for the button but it doesn’t open in the same tab. **Launch(“URL”)** also doesn’t work for **OnSave** or **OnCancel**, I’ve also tried **Launch(“URL”, {}, LaunchTarget.Replace)** but it doesn’t open a new tab at all and doesn’t do anything. The current code I have for the app is below:

```
Button OnSelect:
Launch(“URL”)

OnSave:
SubmitForm(SharePointForm);
Launch(“URL”)

OnCancel:
ResetForm(SharePointForm);
Launch(“URL”)
```

Comment: what does "integrated with a SharePoint list" mean, specifically? Is it a Canvas App or a SharePoint list form customised with PowerApps?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SharePoint list form customised with PowerApps, you won't be able to launch a different site into the same browsers tab. The SharePoint integration keeps the interface strictly in SharePoint.

However, if you place the data into a Canvas PowerApp, you can use a Launch command like this in the OnSuccess property of the form:

```
// some other stuff for saving
UpdateContext({ CurrentItem: Self.LastSubmit, editMode: false, newMode: false });
// launch another URL in the same tab
Launch("http://google.com",{},LaunchTarget.Replace)
```

[image]

For the cancel command you would need to use a button, not a form property.

This works fine in my tests.

NB: if you want to integrate the PowerApps form into the SharePoint list experience, you can create a JSON formatted column that launches the Canvas PowerApp with the list item ID as the parameter. That way, the integration is as seamless as with a SharePoint list form in the side panel.

Answer (score 0):

Using a LaunchTarget with any value other than New in embedded scenarios (for example, Power BI or SharePoint) is not supported and may result in unexpected behavior. In the future, this behavior may change, or may cause an error.

[image]